# can't Copy Element innerHTML to Clipboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I use  clipboard.js for copying my html text with javascript, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<html>
//...
<script src="http://asafdav.github.io/ng-csv/javascripts/ngClip.js"</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
//...
<div id="copy-target">hello</div>
<button class="copy-button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy-target">Copy</button>
//...

<script>
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-button');
</script>
</html>
```

it works very well when I use textarea:

```
<textarea id="copy-target">hello</textarea>
```

but  not ok when I use div:

```
<div id="copy-target">hello</div>
```

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. I think your script tags are wrong- with the code you provided I got a `Clipboard is not defined` error. It looks like you are including [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) but you meant to use [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/)? And then you have a malformed script tag for [ngClip](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-clip) as well.

Try using one of the [CDNs](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/wiki/CDN-Providers) on the project page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.6.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="copy-target">hello</div>
  <button class="copy-button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy-target">Copy</button>
  
  <script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-button');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```